# is it possible to configure custom mac osx app icon set with client-maven-plugin of gluon?

Tags: gluon

I'm experimenting with the client-maven-plugin from Gluon. The output of mvn client:build generates an mac osx app having a default set of icons on the appiconset.

My Question : Is it possible to configure a custom app icon using the gluon client-maven-plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build a JavaFX project with the Client [plugin](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin) for Mac OS or iOS, by default it generates a `gensrc` folder in the `build` folder, where a set of default assets is copied.

You can see a comment printed out:

> Default Mac resources generated in .
>
> Consider copying them to  before performing any modification

This means that you should copy the `mac` folder from `gensrc` to your `src` folder (so you should have `src/mac/Info.plist`, `src/mac/assets`, ...), so the next time you build your app, these assets will be used instead.

Once you have verified this works as expected, you can easily change the included assets with your own, or modify the default plist if needed.

Comment: @Gerben Feel free to click on the tick beside the answer to help others :)

Comment: Run `mvn client:build client:package`, it will create an apk and by default it will create `target/client/aarch64_android/gensrc/android`. It includes the icons and the AndroidManifest.xml. Copy this folder to `src/android`, so you can customize icons and/or manifest.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thx. I tried it before, but I forget the Manifest.xml